# How to replace a letter by another in the structure std::map

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have a `string`

```
std::string test = "test test";
```

I can replace the letter e in that string by another letter using the `replace` function

```
std::replace(test.begin(), test.end(), 'e', 'E');
```

How can I do the same but with a `map<String, Vector<string>>` ?

For example

```
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> myMap;
    
    myMap["test"] = {"test1,test2,test3"};
    myMap["test2"] = {"test21", "test22"};
```

I want to change all the e by E in this map

Comment: "_I want to change all the e by E in this map_" - In the _Keys_ or in the _Values_ or in both?

Comment: @TedLyngmo in both. Is there different solutions if it's only for one of them ?

Comment: Oh yes ... Very

Comment: @inver1123a Instead of giving us your "solution" and trying to make it work, what is the actual high-level problem you're trying to solve?  Ripping up a map of its keys sounds like you're getting into [XY Problem territory](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @JeJo ... or ripping out the node, manipulating it, and then reinserting it since C++17.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's a homework and I have to do it this way, I have been struggling with that that's why I asked here.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see. If it's very complicated to change the keys, how to do it only for the Values ?

Comment: @inver1123a To change the _Keys_, you can [`std::map::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract) the node from the map, fiddle with it, and then reinsert it. Just take one at a time. Change the _Key_, then loop over the `string`s in the _Value_ and change each one as you've done in your question.. Then reinsert the node.

Comment: @inver1123a *it's a homework and I have to do it this way* -- That's not really what I asked.  Did the homework say "how do you take the keys in the map and change them?", or is that what you decided to do?  If it's the former, I am sure there are duplicate links on StackOverflow that shows how to change keys in a map.

Comment: Can this not be done using the same sort of iterators as any other STL container?

Comment: @JeJo One would have to measure. The `extract` function _was_ added to be able to do this kind of thing efficiently.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, my question is a lookalike of my homework "Change all the e by E in the map".

Comment: @TimRandall That what I was looking for.

Comment: Since this is a do my homework question, and SO isn't a "do my homework for me" site, I wrote a function `auto e_to_E(map<string, vector<string>> const& m) -> map<string, vector<string>>` that did the work for, and called it as `myMap = e_to_E(myMap);`

Comment: @Eljay very useful comment.

Comment: You're welcome.  All you need to do is implement the `e_to_E` part, and you're done.  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @inver1123a Btw, do you know what C++ language standard you are being taught? Is it C++17 or newer?

Answer (score 2):

You already know how to perform your replacement operation over a `std::string`. Nothing prevents you from doing the same over a container (on the basis that the container contains strings, which is the case here).

So, for `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>`, you just have to iterate over the map, then over the vectors, and then replace the values the way you want.

But, since you want to perform the replacement not only for the values of the map but also for the keys, it becomes trickier.

As you already know, you can't modify keys in a map. So you have two solutions left, you may either:

- Create new elements {key, value} into the map and remove the old ones afterwards
- Create a new map and overwrite the original one

I think the second solution is the easiest to implement.

---

**Possible implementation:**

What we want is a function that takes a reference to the map and operates the replacements for it.

For the implementation, I decided to go for the second of the above solutions (overwrite the map with the newly created one).

The strategy I have chosen here is:

- To break down the process into several functions and hide the machinery inside a wrapping class.
- As we don't need an instance of this class to run the process, we'll mark the functions as `static`.
- Only the desired function (meant to be used by the user) will be `public` and thus accessible/callable outside of the class.

That would give us:

```
using MyMap = std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>; // For readability purposes

class e2E
{
    private:
        // Get a replaced version of the given string
        static std::string e2E_str(const std::string & s);

        // Get a replaced version of the given map
        static MyMap e2E_MyMap(const MyMap & m);

    public:
        // Compute the replacements over the map
        static void compute(MyMap & m);
};
```

The `e2E_str()` function is just an implementation of the replacement for a `std::string`.
The `e2E_MyMap()` function is the implementation of the process that generates a new map.
The `compute()` function is just the implementation of the overwriting (straightforward by design).

We then obtain:

```
std::string e2E::e2E_str(const std::string & s)
{
    std::string r(s);
    std::replace(r.begin(), r.end(), 'e', 'E');
    return r;
}

MyMap e2E::e2E_MyMap(const MyMap & m)
{
    MyMap result;

    std::string key;
    for(const auto & [k, v] : m)
    {
        key = e2E_str(k);
        result[key] = {};

        for(const std::string & s : v)
            result[key].push_back(e2E_str(s));
    }

    return result;
}

void e2E::compute(MyMap & m)
{
    m = e2E_MyMap(m);
}
```

**Test:**

For readability purposes, we can define a `display()` function to display the map.
It may look like:

```
void display(const MyMap & m, std::ostream & os)
{
    for(const auto & [k, v] : m)
    {
        os << k << ":\n";
        for(const std::string & s : v)
            os << "   " << s << '\n';
    }
    os << std::endl;
}
```

And we can then call our replacement function as follows:

```
int main()
{
    // Create the map
    MyMap my_map {{"test1", {"There", "That", "Word", "The"}}, {"test2", {"This", "Where"}}};

    // Display the map contents before the replacement operation
    display(my_map, std::cout);

    // Perform the replacements
    e2E::compute(my_map);

    // Display the map contents after the replacement operation
    display(my_map, std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to quickly execute and check the results of this test [click here](https://godbolt.org/z/GY4xPo6q8).

Answer (score 1):

For a pre C++17 solution, I recommend creating a new `map`, like @Fareanor has shown.

If you can use C++17 or later there is however another option that doesn't require a second map but involves extracting each data carrying node out of the map, modifying it (including the *Key*) and then inserting the node back into the map.

The same restriction regarding modifying the *Key* while it's still in the map stands, so, loop over the *Key*/*Value* pairs in the map, rip out one node at a time, change it - and put it back into the map.

A pseudo version:

```
for(it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); <no increment> ) {

    next = it + 1;               // save the iterator to next element because ...
    mapnode = myMap.extract(it); // ... `extract` invalidates `it`

    // modify the Key
    cap_e(mapnode.key());        // cap_e() capitalizes 'e' in a string

    // modify the mapped Value
    for every str in mapnode.mapped():
        cap_e(str)

    // re-insert the modified node
    myMap.insert(move(mapnode));

    it = next;                   // set the iterator `it` to what was saved at the top
}
```

Comment: Oh that's great ! I wasn't aware that since C++17 we could get our hands dirty into the map machinery. That being said, I'm not convinced that one should choose `std::map` as a container for one's data if it's meant to modify the keys afterwards.

Comment: @Fareanor Changing a key is sometimes necessary and as you showed, the previous way was to either 1) Delete the key and reinsert the value with a new key or 2) create a completely new map as you did. The node-hack seems to me like a nice way to make this cheaper - although altering the keys in a map is bound to be expensive  one way or the other.